# Do I have a diseased clematis?

Tags: diagnosis

Can anyone identify what is wrong with my clematis?

The leaves are browning and there looks to be a mold or fur growing on it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clematis are usually trouble free.  That white growth looks like [powdery mildew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powdery_mildew).  If the weather has been unusually damp or humid or if the plant is situated where there is poor air circulation these could be causes.

There are "organic" solutions like baking soda suspended in water and sprayed on but I have not found that they work as well as cutting back the plant and improving air circulation.

Or, you can use the classic gardener's solution and ignore it and tell yourself it will do better next year.

Edit: Danny asks if the problem will spread. It's hard to say, different cultivars, slightly different locations indicate that observing is the best policy.

Comment: It's been quite damp but airflow shouldn't be an issue.  Also, there are three plants close to each other and only one is affected.  Is it likely to spread to the others?

I think I'll trim back some growth and give the baking soda a shot until next year.


Thanks